# Add a Sub section for Section in PageLayout

Tags: visualforce

I want to add a subsection for Section in page layout. Is it possible to use Visualforce to add a subsection in any Page  layout? If it is possible please give an explanation with an example.

Comment: Have you read the developer's guide yet? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/

Comment: Thanks for your post..But i want that Subsection for Section in Satndard PageLayout is it possible to do in Page layout?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an inline VisualForce page.

Here is a well documented blog post from Jeff Douglas on the topic. [Use an Inline Visualforce Page with Standard Page Layouts](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/05/08/inline-visualforce-pages-with-standard-page-layouts/)